# Run sql query at the beginning of an Oracle session using DbContext

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, oracle10g, entity-framework-5

The requirement is to execute a sql query using DbContext (EF 5 in DatabaseFirst mode) at the beginning of every Oracle session that DbContext might invoke.
Putting this in the constructor gives inconsistent results because there are instances where this sql query is not run at all when expected.

The setup is EF5 in DBFirst mode connecting to Oracle10gR2 using ODP.NET v12 Managed driver.

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(Constants.SqlQuery);
    }
}
```

I instantiate the context by passing the connecting string because the connection string needs to be dynamic as follows:

```
using(var context = new MyContext(GetConnectionString()))
{
  ...
  ...
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Is there a way to ensure that this query is always run whenever an Oracle session is created?**

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the DbContext class and implement each method to do so. For example....

```
public KashDbContext : DbContext
{
    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(Constants.SqlQuery);
        base.SaveChanges();
    }

    //Do for all methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just implement the `OnContextCreated()` method in your partial class:

```
    partial void OnContextCreated()
    {
        this.ExecuteStoreCommand(Constants.SqlQuery, new object[] { });
    }
```

Comment: I don't know if this would work if there is connection pooling and this changes the behavior of the current connection.

Comment: It works in my connection-pooled application where I need to enable certain Oracle roles each time a connection is established.

Comment: No. I just need to enable the role my application account needs to do anything, because the role is non-default, password-protected.